# Error message when I try to install Microsoft Office 2003 to my new computer running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

This is the error code I get:  Error 1919. Error configuring ODBC data source: Visual FoxPro Database, ODBC error 6: Component not found in the registry. Verify that the file Visual FoxPro Database exists and that you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the error code I get: Error 1919.

This is a known issue with Office 2003.  It is caused by a required but missing registry key.

> When you run the Setup program for any of the programs listed in the "Applies to" section, you may receive the following error message:
>
> **Error 1919. Error configuring ODBC data source: Visual FoxPro Database. ODBC error 0: Verify that the file Visual FoxPro Database exists and that you can access it.**
>
> Cause:
>
> **These problems may occur if the Windows Registry is missing some registry keys.**

You need to install **MDAC 2.8 SP1** in order to prevent this error from happening.

> To resolve this problem, replace the missing registry keys. To do this, use one of the following methods.
>
> Method 1: Install MDAC 2.8
> To install [MDAC 2.8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793), visit the following MSDN Web site:
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937712.aspx

Source:

- ["Error 1919. Error configuring ODBC data source" error messages when you run the Setup
  program for Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/818954/error-1919-error-configuring-odbc-data-source-error-messages-when-you)
- [Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) Installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810805(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.8 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first method of installing Mdac 2.8, restarted my laptop and logged in with my account (which has administrative privileges). This didn't work for me.

Instead, I simply selected "Ignore", and the installation completed successfully. Word operates normally.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the error 1919: The Windows Registry file missing issue, you can try the following methods:

**Method 1:** *Install MDAC 2.8*

**Method 2:** *Reset Registry Keys via Mdac.inf*

**Method 3:** *Import Registry Keys from another PC on the network

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/818954/error-1919-error-configuring-odbc-data-source-error-messages-when-you